# Python convert list to string for xlsx

Tags: python, string, xlsxwriter

Im scrapping some data from html and wanna save it in excel. How can I convert the data in string and lines stored separately?

```
results = soup.find_all("li", {"class": "lvlg"})
for result in results:
   result1 = result.get_text().strip() 
   result1_new = result1.replace('000', '1')
   #print([result1_new])  
   list_lvlg.append(result1_new)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

#convertet string

workbook.close()
```

Comment: What does the data look like and what output are you trying to get?

Comment: To convert a list to a string use: `' '.join(item for item in lst)`.

Comment: @WoLy what do you expect that generator to do?

Comment: str1 = ''.join(list_lvlg)



and



    worksheet.write_string(0, 0, str1)



says 



    98 79 39 79 29 79



And I want in my Excel file one number per Row